# Using ASP.NET MVC app resources in android app

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have web application, created with asp.net MVC4 and I want to create android app based on it. I've done some research, but couldn't choose best option for me. There is few questions which I want to ask:

1)Best way for authentication in this situation? What technologies to use and in what way?

2)What is the best way to get data from my ASP.NET MVC app to my android app (java)? (keeping in mind that some of that data could be personal)

3) Is it possible to make that route/page would be accessible only through mobile app in some  similar way, so that if someone managed to access page from desktop it would't respond?

4)In what format authorization tokens are and what technologies use so I can create it and use it in my app environments? 
Thanks, for help

Answer (score 0):

You may need web api to access mvc 4 in android. For authentication you may include passkey
In order to block access you may block all urls 
You will authorize the user through web service
Yo may see [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-11-26/using-asp.net-web-api-services-in-mobile-apps) , [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1876359.aspx?Web%20API%20for%20Android) and [this](http://wildermuth.com/2013/10/21/Using_ASP_NET_Authentication_in_Web_API)